# How to delay the StreamWriter loop?

Tags: c#, loops, streamwriter

I'm trying to use [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-setout) newbie-handy console "outputer". When I try to apply the loop on it, it either goes nuts producing huge amounts of lines in output file or not working at all if try to use delay. Extremely simplified version of my issue:
C#:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter())
{
    Console.SetOut(writer); 
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }
}
```

I have tried almost every possible way to make a 1sec delay (timers, delays,actions,sleeps). Every option works fine until I apply the StreamWriter. Using delay inside the loop does nothing - tonns of lines "1" in output file. Using delay outside the loop keeps the output file empty. "Try-Catch" says nothing. Guys, where is the trouble? Maybe StreamWriter is not delay-compatible?

Comment: `I have tried almost every possible way to make a 1sec delay` Show your code... http://sscce.org/

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) didn't work?

Comment: Thread.Sleep(1000) will probably do

Comment: @Dirk Trilsbeek Works fine for console. Applying it in loop using StreamWriter  keeps output file empty.

Comment: `using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{


static void Main()
{
    
         using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("out.txt"))
   
        {
            Console.SetOut(writer); 
              
            while (true)
            {
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
      
  Console.WriteLine("1");
  
            }
        }
  }


}`

Lefts empty console and output both.

Comment: @Rooger I suggest to edit the answer and show the code there.

Comment: @Rooger: seems to be an issue with StreamWriter not flushing. Your loop never ends, so StreamWriter can't flush. Set writer.AutoFlush to true and you will see your console output appear in the file while the program is running.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/passy/637319

Comment: @Dirk Trilsbeek thanks so much! You are absolutely right!

Comment: @ Dirk Trilsbeek `using (var writer = new StreamWriter("out.txt"))
        {
            Console.SetOut(writer);
     writer.AutoFlush = (true);

outputs 2 results only and all the rest AFTER the program closing. Do I need to add smth else?
   
            while (true)
            {   Act();
          Thread.Sleep(1000);
    
                }
                
  
  }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your file will only be closed and written for sure when the `using` block ends. Before, it's up to your operating system and disk's caching mechanism to actually *write* the file.

Your loop never ends. Your file might never get written. See to it that your loop can be terminated normally and the using block can close the file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Thread.Sleep and specify the timespan you want to sleep inside your loop. You also need to terminate the loop at some point, for example:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\temp.txt"))
{
    Console.SetOut(writer);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly. The problem was in non-flushing writer!